# Poor performance due to hyper-threading with OpenMP: how to bind threads to cores

Tags: gcc, openmp, scheduler, hyperthreading

I am developing large dense matrix multiplication code.  When I profile the code it sometimes gets about 75% of the peak flops of my four core system and other times gets about 36%.  The efficiency does not change between executions of the code.  It either starts at 75% and continues with that efficiency or starts at 36% and continues with that efficiency.

I have traced the problem down to hyper-threading and the fact that I set the number of threads to four instead of the default eight. **When I disable hyper-threading in the BIOS I get about 75% efficiency consistently (or at least I never see the drastic drop to 36%).**

Before I call any parallel code I do `omp_set_num_threads(4)`.  I have also tried `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` before I run my code but it seems to be equivalent.

I don't want to disable hyper-threading in the BIOS.  I think I need to bind the four threads to the four cores.  I have tested some different cases of `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` but so far I still have the problem that the efficiency is 36% sometimes.  **What is the mapping with hyper-threading and cores?**  E.g. do thread 0 and thread 1 correspond to the the same core and thread 2 and thread 3 another core?

**How can I bind the threads to each core without thread migration so that I don't have to disable hyper-threading in the BIOS?**  Maybe I need to look into using [sched_setaffinity](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html)?

Some details of my current system: Linux kernel 3.13, GCC 4.8,Intel Xeon E5-1620 (four physical cores, eight hyper-threads).

Edit:
This seems to be working well so far

```
export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
```

or

```
export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-7"
```

Edit:
This seems also to work well

```
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true
```

Edit:
[These options](http://www.glennklockwood.com/comp/affinity.php) also work well (gemm is the name of my executable)

```
numactl -C 0,1,2,3 ./gemm
```

and

```
taskset -c 0,1,2,3 ./gemm
```

Comment: Since export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7" gives good results I guess that means that thread 0 and 4 are core 0, thread 1 and 5 are core2, ... i.e. the threads are assigned like electrons in orbitals.  It first fills each core (thread 0-3 )and when all cores have a thread it goes back and assign remain threads to the same core (threads 4-7).

Comment: Both `hwloc-ls` from the hwloc library or `cpuinfo` from Intel MPI provide essential topology information about the machine, e.g. mapping of logical CPU numbers to physical cores/threads. The numbering depends on the BIOS but in my experience most cases have been that hyperthreads are cycled in an "outer loop". Also, you could use the shorthand notation `"0-7"`.

Comment: @HristoIliev, for portability it seems the right way to do this is to use OMP_PLACES, e.g. `export OMP_PLACES=cores` from OpenMP4.0.  On AMD systems each module only has one FPU but gets two threads and I think it's assigned linearly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780554/what-limits-scaling-in-this-simple-openmp-program/19871592#19871592 so doing GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-7" won't work I think.  Actually, OMP_PROC_BIND=true might be fine then as well.  Maybe that's the best solution.

Comment: My comment was only that `"0-7"` is the same as `"0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7"`. With libgomp `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` is practically the same as `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-(#cpus-1)"`, i.e. there is no topology awareness, at least for versions before 4.9.

Comment: @HristoIliev, oh, I understand.  In that case OMP_PROC_BIND=true on AMD might not work.  I might have to do GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7" with AMD (I don't have a system to test it on).  The only advantage then of OMP_PROC_BIND is that GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY depends on GCC.

Comment: `OMP_PROC_BIND` is supposed to enable some sort of implementation-specific binding. The _places_ feature in OpenMP 4.0 introduces the way for the user to control that binding in an abstract way. With pre-4.0 implementations you should run `hwloc-ls` or `cpuinfo` in order to get the actual topology (or parse `/proc/cpuinfo` on your own).

Comment: @HristoIliev, thanks, I think I understand now.  I parsed /proc/cpuinfo on my single socket system and my four socket NUMA system.  It appears the topology is equivalent to `KMP_AFFINITY=granularity=fine,scatter` with ICC.  This is what I want with Intel proccessors.  I don't know what the topology is on AMD but I think AMD cores are seen really as distinct cores (they are for integers but not for floats) and is not module aware.  That means I have to do something different for AMD systems.  That's annoying.

Comment: On AMD CPU's I had to use GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-24:2" to get decent performance. Cores without FPU are just fake cores to me in this century.

Comment: @VladimirF, thanks, that's what I suspected for AMD.  That's means I have to do something different for AMD than Intel.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but it might be worth looking in to: [apparently, hyperthreading can cause your cache to thrash](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/310905). Have you tried checking out valgrind to see what kind of issue is causing your problem? There might be a quick fix to be had from allocating some junk at the top of every thread's stack so that your threads don't end up kicking each others cache lines out.

[It looks like your CPU is 4-way set associative](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20E5-1650.html) so it's not insane to think that, across 8 threads, you might end up with some really unfortunately aligned accesses. If your matrices are aligned on a multiple of the size of your cache, and if you had pairs of threads accessing areas a cache-multiple apart, any incidental read by a third thread would be enough to start causing conflict misses.

For a quick test -- if you change your input matrices to something that's not a multiple of your cache size (so they're no longer aligned on a boundary) and your problems disappear, then there's a good chance that you're dealing with conflict misses.

Comment: I should use valgrind at some point ( have never used it).  But the fact that hyper-threading makes things worse is not surprising in my code.  Hyper-threading is useful for non-optimized code.  Also, when I run GEMM in MKL it uses four threads on my system and not eight.  For certain hihgly optimized code hyper-threading actually gives worse results.