# OpenMP parallell region overhead increase when num_threads varies

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I was trying to use different number of threads in different parts of a program to achieve the maximum acceleration. However it is found that switching the thread number using the num_threads clause incurs significant overhead. I am looking for an explanation for this, since according to my understanding the thread pool should always contain a given number of threads, regardless of the actual number that got invoked. I am also looking for possible work-arounds against this. Thanks.

Sample code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<omp.h>

void omp_sum(int ntd) {
    int s = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(ntd)
    {
        int i = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp atomic
        s += i;
    }
}   

int main()
{
    int N = 100;
    int NT1 = 6, NT2 = 12;
    double t;

    t = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int n=0;n<N;n++) {
        omp_sum(NT1);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", (omp_get_wtime() - t) * 1e6 );

    t = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int n=0;n<N;n++) {
        omp_sum(NT2);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", (omp_get_wtime() - t) * 1e6 );

    t = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int n=0;n<N;n++) {
        omp_sum(NT1);
        omp_sum(NT1);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", (omp_get_wtime() - t) * 1e6 );

    t = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int n=0;n<N;n++) {
        omp_sum(NT2);
        omp_sum(NT2);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", (omp_get_wtime() - t) * 1e6 );

    t = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int n=0;n<N;n++) {
        omp_sum(NT1);
        omp_sum(NT2);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", (omp_get_wtime() - t) * 1e6 );
}
```

Sample output (in us):

```
1034.069001
1058.620000
1034.572000
2210.681000
18234.355000
```

**EDIT**:
The workstation running the code has 2 hexa-core Intel E5-2630L CPUs, so there should be a total of 12 hardware cores and 24 hyperthreads. I was using Fedora 19 with GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us what compiler did you use. Each compiler comes with its own OpenMP runtime and they all differ in the way they implement the thread teams.

Comment: I can reproduce your results with GCC 4.8 on my four core system/eight hyper thread system.  I changed N1 to 4 and N2 to 8.  I assume the overhead to switch the number of threads (even if it does not have to create a new pool) is much larger than to do six or 12 atomic sums.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your results with GCC 4.8 (g++ -O3 -fopenmp foo.cpp) on my four core system/eight hyper thread system.  I changed N1 to 4 and N2 to 8.

Your function `omp_sum` is simple

```
pushq   %rbx    
movq    %rdi, %rbx
call    omp_get_thread_num
movq    (%rbx), %rdx
lock addl   %eax, (%rdx)
popq    %rbx
ret
```

Here is the assembly code for the loop

```
for(int n=0;n<N;n++) {
    omp_sum(NT1);
    omp_sum(NT2);
}

.L10
leaq    32(%rsp), %rsi
xorl    %ecx, %ecx
movl    $4, %edx
movl    $_Z7omp_sumi._omp_fn.0, %edi
movl    $0, 28(%rsp)
movq    %rbx, 32(%rsp)
call    GOMP_parallel
leaq    32(%rsp), %rsi
xorl    %ecx, %ecx
movl    $8, %edx
movl    $_Z7omp_sumi._omp_fn.0, %edi
movl    $0, 28(%rsp)
movq    %rbx, 32(%rsp)
call    GOMP_parallel
subl    $1, %ebp
jne .L10
```

This is almost identical to the assembly for the loop

```
for(int n=0;n<N;n++) {
    omp_sum(NT2);
    omp_sum(NT2);
}
```

The only change being `movl $4, %edx` instead of `movl  $8, %edx`. So it's hard to see what is causing the problem. All the magic happens in GOMP_parallel. One would have to look at the source code of GOMP_parallel but my guess is that GOMP_parallel checks the number of threads that were last used in a parallel call and if the new parallel call uses a different number of threads it has some overhead to switch.  That overhead is much larger than your simple function.

But I'm not sure why this would ever be a problem. In practice it does not make sense to use such short parallel sections (one would parallelize a loop and N would be much larger) so the overhead should not be problem.

**Edit:** Section 2.41 of the OpenMP 3.1 specification titled "Determining the Number of Threads for a parallel Region" gives the algorithm for determining the number of threads. [The source code for GOMP_parallel from GCC-4.8](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/gcc-4_8-branch/libgomp/parallel.c) shows that the first function it calls is `gomp_resolve_num_threads`.

Comment: The code is an abstraction of a particle simulator. I'm trying to push the strong scaling limit of the simulator, which means that the amount of work on each node are probably just comparable to the launch overhead. Within the program I noticed that different regions achieve their own optimal performance with different number of threads, probably due to the intrinsic parallelism of each region. So that is where this motivation of using different num_threads come from.

Comment: Right now the work-around that I found is to launch the same amount (max) of threads anyway, but only distribute work manually among the first n_optimal threads. The code is a scientific computing code so wasting cores is not a big problem as long as the overall computation gets faster.

Comment: @Rainn, I have something similar in some matrix multiplication code.  Part of it benefits from hyper-threading and another part actually does worse with hyper threading. I tried setting the number number of thread for each differently, eight and four, but the results were worse than using all eight or all four.  I got the best results with four but only sometimes and the most consistent results with eight.  Once I bound the threads I get the best results by using four everywhere now.  I have not gone back to see if binding the threads would allow me to use four and eight again.

Comment: @Rainn, you might want to try [binding your threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368576/poor-performance-due-to-hyper-threading-with-openmp-how-to-bind-threads-to-core).

Comment: Binding is not helping in that case. Actually binding dramatically worsens things (as in time increases by orders of magnitude) with GOMP. Interestingly enough, both GOMP and Intel's OpenMP runtime exhibit that behaviour.

Comment: Btw, you've linked to the master version of the GCC source tree which includes the OpenMP 4.0 features. The code there is way more complex than the one in the 4.8.x branch of libgomp.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I was referring to binding the threads in his real code not this test case.  I can't imagine why any real code would look like this test case.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I corrected the link to point to the GCC-4.8 branch of GOMP.  I did not notice big differences at least for parallel.c...

Comment: @HristoIliev I just tested CPU binding on my real code (with the work-around I mentioned above) and observed ~3% performance increase, which is not bad. I didn't go back to the variable num_threads version to check though.

Comment: @HristoIliev - weird, which intel compiler/runtime were you using?  I see this behavior on gcc 4.6,4.7,and 4.8, but not with icc 12, 13, or 14.

Comment: @JonathanDursi, could be because I tested GCC 4.8.2 and Intel 14.0.2 on one of the login nodes of our cluster which has an 8-socket board (64 cores in total). Will try on more systems on Monday.

Comment: @JonathanDursi I just tested the sample code with Intel 14.0.2. I didn't see this behavior either. Timing: 4299.879074, 6644.010544
518.798828, 752.925873, 2009.153366